# Dynamic appendChild inside AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to web development.

I have rendered text from ajax success function. I would like to add canvas under each text line.

Inside AJAX success, I tried below two, texts are rendered successfully and text id are successfully dynamic assigned but they both failed with `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`, I think there's problem with `document.getElementById('result'+idx).appendChild(canv);` as if I use `document.body.appendChild(canv);` I get the canvases but not at the desired location.

I have no idea why `getElementById` gets null, I tried `'result'+idx.toString()` as well, but it does not work either.

```
$.each(cat_result, function(idx, value) { 
text.append('<id="result'+idx+'">'+'<br>');
canvas_and_plot(idx,cat_result[idx][8],cat_result[idx][9],cat_result[idx][10])
});
$('#result').replaceWith(text);
```

```
$.each(cat_result, function(idx, value) { 
text.append('<id="result'+idx+'">'+'<br>');
});
$('#result').replaceWith(text);
$.each(cat_result, function(idx, value) { 
canvas_and_plot(idx,cat_result[idx][8],cat_result[idx][9],cat_result[idx][10])
});
```

HTML

```
<p class="result-box" id="result-box">The result is : <br><strong id="result"></strong></p>
```

JS function

```
function canvas_and_plot(idx,a,b,c) {
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
canv.width = 200;
canv.height = 200;
canv.setAttribute('id', 'canv_'+idx);
canv.style.position = 'relative';
canv.style.float = 'left';
document.getElementById('result'+idx).appendChild(canv); // Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
//other code that does the plotting
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger to step through the JS code? I suggest researching the debugger your browser, set some break points, and step through your code to determine what is null and why. It's likely that your id on your getElementById is incorrect, and it's returning null, and a null object wont have a .appendChild() method. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: @AndyStagg thanks for the response.I figured the same. Sorry if not clear in the question. But I still have no idea why getElementById gets null. I just tried `'result'+idx.toString()` as well but it does not work. I know the very basic of debugging in Chrome but am not sure how to further debug this problem.

Comment: are your trying to target the "result-box" element?

Comment: @AndyStagg No I am not, I created result_0, result_1... using  `<id="result'+idx+'">` and want to have canv_0 target to  result_0, canv_1 to result_1 and etc.

Comment: If you're targeting result_0 then... getElementById('result_'+idx)

Comment: it's possibly also something to do with this line `<id="result_0">` might be the issue - it's not valid syntax. `<element attribute="value">` is correct... so what element is id supposed to be?

Comment: @AndyStagg It was supposed to be result0, result1, sorry for the typo. I have figured this out by hardcoding canvas HTML in the loop. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById('"result'+idx+'"').appendChild(canv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why formatting around `getElementById` does not work after multiple varied attempts.
I worked around by using plain canvas HTML to create canvas in `text.append` and it works.